# Python Turtle: How to do onkeypress to a function in another file

Tags: python, function, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, calling-convention

I have this issue in python turtle that when I attempt to do the onkeypress feature for a function that is in another file, nothing occurs. No error messages, no character movement. Nothing.

File 1 (Player Function and Creating Sprite):

```
class Player:
    global player
    import turtle
    player = turtle.Turtle()
    player.penup()
    player.color("red")
    player.shape("square")
    player.shapesize(2, 2)
    
def moved(x, y):
    player.forward(50)
```

File 2 (imports the function and when key pressed activates function):

```
import turtle

from Player import Player
from Player import moved

sc = turtle.Screen()
sc.title("Alpha")
sc.bgcolor("Gray")

sc.onkeypress(moved, "u")

sc.mainloop()
```

I tried to use the normal feature to do this, but it just didn't work. Someone please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a call to [`sc.listen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.listen), which is required to enable key listeners.

Next, the callback to `onkeypress` should accept 0 parameters, not 2. The `x` and `y` parameters are used for clicks. What `x` and `y` values would be relevant to a key press?

Furthermore, you don't need the `global` keyword here and imports should occur at the top of files. If `moved` (should be named `move`, a verb) is associated with the `Player`, then it should be in the class. We might as well make it an instance-based class rather than a simple namespace. The convention is that files/modules are lowercase in Python.

Here's a re-write suggestion:

`player.py`:

```py
import turtle

class Player:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.turtle = t = turtle.Turtle()
        t.penup()
        t.color("red")
        t.shape("square")
        t.shapesize(2, 2)

    def move(self):
        self.turtle.forward(50)
```

`main.py`:

```py
import turtle
from player import Player

sc = turtle.Screen()
sc.title("Alpha")
sc.bgcolor("Gray")
player = Player()

sc.onkeypress(player.move, "u")
sc.listen()

sc.exitonclick()
```